# Create properly escaped string from byte array

Tags: c#, unicode, meteor, type-conversion

I have a byte array, read from an image file, that I am trying to send from C# across a socket to a Meteor server running collectionFS (v0.3.7).

I am trying to convert it to a string to match the result I would get from calling `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` in JavaScript, for example:

```
?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0003?\u0000\u0000\u0002?
```

In my C# code, I have tried using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`, which gives me something like this:

```
�PNG\r\n\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0�\0\0
```

This fails on the transfer, presumably because the '\0' is treated like the end of the string.

Can anyone better explain what is happening here? Is there a nice way in C# to format the bytes using the unicode escape sequences like `readAsBinaryString()` does?

EDIT: The eventual destination for this data is a BSON binary entry in MongoDB (in Meteor), to be later extracted (as  a Blob) and viewed through the normal Meteor web browser client.

Comment: Would simply encoding every byte as hex work (much easier, plenty of duplicates)?

Comment: I can try that, although I suspect that it needs the unicode escaping for some reason. I'll update the question, but the eventual destination for this data is a BSON binary entry in MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in method that does exactly that.

To transform byte array to encoded you need to decide what is encoded and what is not. Looks like `0-9a-zA-Z` range should not be encoded and the rest encoded as `\uXXXX`:

I'd do something like following:

```
var result = String.Join("", byteArray
   .Select(b => b >'0' && b <'9' ? 
       (char)b.ToString() : String.Format(@"\u{0:x4}", b)));
```

Comment: Interesting, this mostly works, but I had to change it to `((char)b.ToString())`. I don't understand this encoding, it seems to be some weird hybrid of systems. Thanks though!

Comment: @WildCrustacean - inlined your code fix - thanks. Consider converting check for "bytes not to convert" into `HashSet.Contains` if you decide more than 0-9 characters should not be converted.